# Iterating two array of diferents objects using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have two arrays of different objects but one of its values is the one that makes the connection between them as if it were a foreign key.
I would like to add one of the values of one object to the other but using Linq or in a way that is cleaner than this:

```
    public static List<GroupSimpleModel> ToModelWithMark(List<GroupSimpleEntity> groups, List<GroupMarkedEntity> markGroups)
        {
            List<GroupSimpleModel> groupSimpleModelsMarked = new List<GroupSimpleModel>();
            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                GroupSimpleModel groupSimpleModelMarked = new GroupSimpleModel()
                {
                    Code = group.Code,
                    Id = group.Id,
                    ParentId = group.ParentId,
                    ProfileId = group.ProfileId,
                    MarkedTypeCodes = new List<string>()
                    
                };
                foreach (var mark in markGroups)
                {
                    if (mark.GroupId == group.Id)
                    {
                        groupSimpleModelMarked.MarkedTypeCodes.Add(mark.MarkedTypeCode);
                    }
                }
                groupSimpleModelsMarked.Add(groupSimpleModelMarked);
            }
            return groupSimpleModelsMarked;
        }
```

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Nice accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709560/linq-in-line-property-update-during-join

Comment: @MattEvans Its Ok but dont work for me because I want to return a model of an entity, and that response works if I want to return the same kind of object. My fault for dont explain it on the question

Comment: @DragandDrop I want all coincidences because one group can have more than one mark

Comment: Please provide the source of model/entity classes as well.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride its not needed, I think the question is too clear

Comment: But it makes it harder to test solutions, because I had to create the model classes myself.

Comment: @DragandDrop do you really consider an `if` nested inside a loop nested inside a loop "clean"? Nested loops on their own are unclean in my opinion. Especially when they can be expressed with `Join()` or `GroupJoin()`. And the `if` is just the cherry on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accepted answer is suboptimal, because it does a linear search repeatedly. [`GroupJoin()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin?view=net-7.0) can do that search for you and will so only once:

```cs
var result = groups.GroupJoin(
    markGroups,
    g => g.Id,
    gm => gm.GroupId,
    (g, gms) => new GroupSimpleModel {
        Code = g.Code,
        Id = g.Id,
        ParentId = g.ParentId,
        ProfileId = g.ProfileId,
        MarkedTypeCodes = gms.Select(gm => gm.MarkedTypeCode).ToList()
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Just translate from your code:

```
groups.Select(group => new GroupSimpleModel()
       {
           Code = group.Code,
           Id = group.Id,
           ParentId = group.ParentId,
           ProfileId = group.ProfileId,
           MarkedTypeCodes = markGroups.Where(mark => mark.GroupId == group.Id)
                                       .Select(mark => mark.MarkedTypeCode)
                                       .ToList();
       })
      .ToList();
```

Comment: This has complexity `O(n*m)` and will quickly decrease in performance for larger input sets. Why not just use `GroupJoin()` which would prevent this?

Comment: It's just a simple conversion without considering performance. I agree GroupJoin is better.